# Responsiveness of the annotations in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, annotations, jstockchart

[without full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP0WC.png)

[on full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeHSK.png)

In StockChart of highcharts whenever I use Measure (X,Y,XY) annotation and switch to full screen, the annotation does not reflow or is not consistent with the scale.

Is there a way to correct that?

https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui

Comment: Hi @Pratyush Garg, That problem is a bug in Highcharts, I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11174. I will try to provide you some workaround soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem is a bug in Highcharts and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11174

As a workaround, you can update measure annotations in `redraw` event:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function() {
            this.annotations.forEach(function(annotation) {
                if (annotation.options.type === 'measure') {
                    annotation.update();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xc6eo0f7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw